# setting up a web stack with nginx?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, ip-address, load-balancing

I have got a dedicated server that has nginx web server located in a uk datacenter, the ngnix acts as a front end server which then directs users to other instances that i have on aws located in america. What ip address would the client see, the ngnix front server(which is the desired result), or would the client still know about the instances or servers ip address located in america?

PS. nginx acts as a load balancer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, users connect to "www.yoursite.com", and that gets looked up in DNS.

Assuming there is only one DNS entry (corresponding your nginx frontend), then as far as those users are concerned, they are only talking to that one machine.

Sometimes people use round-robin DNS, where multiple machines correspond to a given host name.
Presumably you would know if you were doing this, though (:

You can confirm this by tracing your traffic when connecting. Maybe use [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/)?